# Solve $8p^2 + 5p = 0$ by factorising

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can we solve this by factorising?

$$8p^2 + 5p = 0$$

I know how to factorise it,

$$p(8p + 5) = 0$$

However I do not know how to solve it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you heard of the Zero Product Property?

Comment: If the product of two integers, rational numbers or real numbers is zero, then one of the two numbers must be zero.

Comment: So I'm assuming the +5 goes to after `=`, thus turning negative and is then divided by 8? Therefore being `p=-5/8` right? I'm not sure if that's right..

Comment: Can you see any other possibility?

Comment: @EthanWebster Yes, that's right.

Comment: Okay, thanks much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$p(8p+5)=0$ if and only if $p=0$ or $8p+5=0$. This is equivalent to $p=0$ or $p=-\frac{5}{8}$.

Comment: Should be "and/or".

Comment: Oh. Didn't know that. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

$$8p^2+5p=0\\
\implies p(8p+5)=0\\
\implies \boxed{p=0\text{ And/Or }8p+5=0.}\\
\text{Take a stab at solving the above linear equation.}$$

Comment: Thank you, although I wanted to know how to find the value of `p`, but I got it now :)

Comment: @EthanWebster Sure! :-)